# How to add text shadow to Twitter Bootstrap navbar links?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors, less, navbar

So far I've tried:

```
.navbar-inner {
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
```

And:

```
.nav > li > a {
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
```

Neither works. What gives?

FYI my navbar html code is the same as the Twitter Bootstrap demo code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Test Inc.</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what browser(s) are you testing it on?

Comment: The problem here for you was "specificity" ... since Twitter Bootstrap is being more specific about how it's adding the styles by starting their selector from `.navbar > .nav > li > a` so their CSS was winning over yours because it was a more specific selector.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a{
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
```

Demo: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8nn2r/)

one advice use px instead of em because bootstrap uses px

Comment: I'd use rem if I have to extend bootstrap. It uses px to define base lengths, but then work out all dependent classes in rem's.